# Choose CSS style using C# Code (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have two classes in my embedded CSS in my Default.aspx page. I can transfer the code to external CSS if needed.

Can I make a code in C# where after clicking a button, I choose between the two styles for my table?
I'm very new to ASP and C#.

My classes (embedded):

```
   .tftable
    {
        background-color: Blue;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #333333;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #729ea5;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .CSSTable
    {
        background-color: Gray;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%; /*Fits the <div>*/
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;

    }
```

So after clicking 1 button, my table class will choose "tftable" and another button will choose "CSS" table class.

Regards

Comment: You want to make this simple CSS class change in server side or in client side? Do you need to execute any logic onclick of button in server or just want to change this css class?

Comment: Server-side, clicking a button via C# code.

Answer (score 0):

its not c# code, that is javascript code

Add A style link with Id as below

```
<link href="css/style1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="stylesheet" />
```

Then Create a Javascript Function to change the Css file

```
function changeStyle(name){
    if(name=='style1')
        document.getElementById('stylesheet').href='css/style1.css';
    else if(name=='style2')
        document.getElementById('stylesheet').href='css/style2.css';
    else if(name=='style3')
        document.getElementById('stylesheet').href='css/style3.css';
}
```

Call that function in Your Buttons

```
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:changeStyle('style1')">Style1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:changeStyle('style2')">Style2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:changeStyle('style3')">Style3</a></li>
</ul>
```

reference

http://www.qualitycodes.com/tipdemos/javascript/dynamic-css/
http://www.qualitycodes.com/tip/14/dynamically-choosingchanging-a-css-file.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to use same css file for the both styles, if so try this once.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTable.Attributes.Add("class", "tftable");
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTable.Attributes.Add("class", "CSSTable");
}
```

Comment: I think you mean to use the `class` attribute

Comment: It would also be simpler to have just `myTable.Attributes("style") = xxx`.  You don't need to remove it before adding it back

Comment: Using `.Add` will fail if you already have `class` in the attribute collection... look more closely at my 2nd comment.  (I've just noticed that I used `style` in my 2nd comment, which obviously should be `myTable.Attributes("class") = xxx`)